# How do I execute a function from external Javascript file using Python and Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and am stuck trying to get it to automatically open links that look like this:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=javascript:myFunction(argument1, argument2)>Click here</a>
```

The `myFunction` function is in an external .js file. I couldn't fetch it from the server (this is material for another question) so I copied and pasted it into a text file that I have saved on my hard drive. I load and run it with

```
with open ('MY_PATH', 'r') as f:
     ext_js = f.read()

driver.execute_script(ext_js)
```

which runs without a problem. But then when I try to run

```
driver.execute_script("myFunction(argument1, argument2)")
```

I get the following error:

```
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: myFunction is not defined
```

Shouldn't it have been imported when I have executed the external .js file? How do I get my code to see it?

Comment: how about `driver.execute_script(ext_js + "\n" + "myFunction(argument1, argument2)")` ?

Comment: did you try find element and `click()` ? Selenium should run `myFunction` assigned to `onclick` when you use `click()`

Comment: When I run `driver.execute_script(ext_js + "\n" + "myFunction(argument1, argument2)")`, I get the error `JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Invalid regular expression flags`.

When I find the links and then use `click()`, nothing happens. Not even an error message. I'm using a headful browser and it does not go to the link's location.

Comment: is this working when you click normally in web browser - without selenium? what is URL for this page?

Comment: No, it wasn't working; thanks for pointing me to that. I also figured out why: I've been using ProxyCrawler to access the site (I'm scraping it) and it seems these links become dead if I get the page through ProxyCrawler. As soon as I tried accessing the site directly, the `click()` method worked. I guess now I have to go post a question on how I can get it to work with ProxyCrawler.