# Cannot follow links on page when scraping with proxies

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, proxy

I am scraping pages like this one:

[site to scrape](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=both&NA=ZW&DE=AE&user=KQ&subuser=KQ)

I am using Python with Selenium and connecting through ProxyCrawler. One of the things I need to do is follow all the links that say *For details, click here* and grab the text there. The links look like this:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=javascript:submitLink('TIDFT/AE/VI/IS/ID100201','KQ','KQ')>For details, click here</a>
```

As you can see, each link's URL gets constructed by a function called `submitLink`. The function is not defined in the page source; rather it is called from an external .js file referenced in the head. I tried injecting the file into the DOM to make the function run but failed so far. For more details, see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65452211/how-do-i-execute-a-function-from-external-javascript-file-using-python-and-selen).

So I'm trying instead to click each link to make the script run. However, this doesn't work with ProxyCrawler. If I connect directly, the links work fine but obviously that exposes my scraper.

Here is the minimum workable code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib import parse

apikey = MY_KEY

scrapeurl = 'https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=both&NA=' + \
            'ZW' + '&DE=' + 'AE' + '&user=KQ&subuser=KQ'
selenurl = 'https://api.proxycrawl.com/?token=' + apikey + '&url=' + parse.quote(scrapeurl)

DRIVER_PATH = '/Applications/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get(selenurl)
#driver.get(scrapeurl)

link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@onclick, 'submitLink')]")
link.click()
```

The above works is I use `scrapeurl`. It doesn't work with `selenurl`. Is there a way to use ProxyCrawler and still be able to click on those links?

Comment: an alternative would be to find out the href of each link and navigate through get

Comment: The href of each link just says `javascript:void(0)`. I edited the question to include that information. The reason I need to click the links is so that an external script runs and constructs the URL for me. That's what `submitLink` does, and it is defined in that external script. I tried getting the .js file to import the function but failed so far. See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65452211/how-do-i-execute-a-function-from-external-javascript-file-using-python-and-selen).